# Set label under a stylized checkbox

Tags: css, css-selectors, font-awesome

based on [this](http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/yILjk/)
I stylized my checkboxes with awesome font.
But I would like to center the label below my checkboxes. I have seen several solutions with classic checkboxes, but I dont understand how to do it in this case.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input id="box1" type="checkbox" class="bus"/>
  <label for="box1">Checkbox 1</label>
  <input id="box2" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="box2">Checkbox 2</label>
  <input id="box3" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="box3">Checkbox 3</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*** custom checkboxes ***/

input[type=checkbox] { display:none; } /* to hide the checkbox itself */
input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label:before { content: "\f096"; } /* unchecked icon */
input[type=checkbox] + label:before { letter-spacing: 10px; } /* space between checkbox and label */

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before { content: "\f18d"; } /*

checked icon */
input.bus[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before { content: "\f080"; color: red} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before { letter-spacing: 5px; } /* allow space for check mark */
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should divide the label to `::before` element and `<span>` inside:

```
<label for="box1"><span>Checkbox 1</span></label>
```

Then treat ::before element like a normal element which you want to position inside the label, for example:

```
/* label position */
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -10px;
}
```

Note that checkbox was centered horizontally using this trick, only with changed axis: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

JSFiddle (without FontAwesome included, but you got the feeling):
https://jsfiddle.net/aojt0vh0/

Comment: thanks, but now the checked box are correctly above the label, but not the unckecked ones. I changed the position to absolute in your exemple, otherwise the checked box is in the center of the div, not the input. There is still an issue with the uncheked boxes: https://jsfiddle.net/051cr5hg/1/

Comment: Well then you should probably check the code and change it to work from only checked inputs to all inputs: https://jsfiddle.net/051cr5hg/2/

Comment: thanks for your help, the answer is good but i think there are some limitations, as when resizing the window. When resizing as small as possible, the icons are not centered anymore.

Comment: And how much do you expect your users to resize? No answer works for every "as small as possible" size.